# How to test Jackson CsvSchema library?

Tags: java, jackson, junit5, quarkus, jacoco

I would like to do a unit test of this example here:

https://huongdanjava.com/convert-json-to-csv-using-jackson-library.html

I'm new to unit testing I don't understand much about it.

I would like to test this example to get coverage of Jacoco.

Comment: I think your best approach here is to first read the JUnit 5 website, there will be lots of useful information on testing and on how to use JUnit 5 to accomplish unit test., and also look for JUnit 5 and Jacoco tutorials.  Finally Jackson is a well used library, and I would expect it to already have a test suite, which you should be able to find included in its source repository.

Comment: Helo  Gavin, i've read a lot about Junit and Jacoco, about Jackson I can't find any example about csv.    So I would like an example how to do it.   My Api is using the same code above with little modification.